# AS2 to AS3 conversion errors

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have used ActionScript 2 for Flash files but since the ActionScript 2 doesn't support by any browser, I need to change my ActionScript 2 code to ActionScript 3.

While I was trying to convert using Adobe Animate, it started to show some errors in image loading with preloader, initial settings, vertical/ horizontal alignment and so on.

The code and the error messages are given below:

```
//Controls Default
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
controls.zo.useHandCursor = false;
controls.zi.useHandCursor = false;
controls.br.useHandCursor = false;
controls.bl.useHandCursor = false;
controls.bu.useHandCursor = false;
controls.bd.useHandCursor = false;
controls.bres.useHandCursor = false;
resized_ = false;
cursor._visible = panWithinBoundary ? false : true;
//Image loading with preloader (if the settings made to load the image dynamically)
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
if (image ne undefined and image ne "" and image ne null) {
    //If image path specified:
    controls._visible = false;
    mcl = new MovieClipLoader();
    tempMc = content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder.Content.createEmptyMovieClip("temp", 1);
    mcl.loadClip(image, tempMc);
    mcl.onLoadStart = function() {
        //Image loading progress
        loader.start_(tempMc);
    };
    mcl.onLoadInit = function(mc) {
        //After loading the image:
        if (imageSmoothing and image.substr(image.lastIndexOf(".")+1) ne "swf") {
            //If imageSmoothing is set 'true' and the content is not swf, we need to capture the bitmap data
            //for better look:If imageSmoothing is set 'false' or the content is not an image (but swf), 
            //we should show the content 'as is' without bitmap capture.
            myBmp = new flash.display.BitmapData(mc._width, mc._height, true, 0x00CCCCCC);
            myBmp.draw(mc);
            removeMovieClip(mc);
            content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder.Content.attachBitmap(myBmp, 0, "auto", true);
        }
        loader.unloadMovie();
        bgShade.unloadMovie();
        init();
        run();
    };
} else {
    //If image path not specified, then assuming image is placed directly to the library:
    loader.unloadMovie();
    bgShade.unloadMovie();
    init();
    run();
}
//Initial settings
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function init() {
    recent = 0;
    posx = posy=0;
    canvasSize();
    iw = cW;
    ih = cH;
    mask_._width = hit._width=iw;
    mask_._height = hit._height=ih;
    cr_width = iw;
    cr_height = ih;
    ease = ease<1 ? 1 : ease;
    zoomFactor = zoomFactor<.3 ? .3 : zoomFactor;
    panSpeed = panSpeed<1 ? 1 : panSpeed;
    mSP = 1;
    mPX=_xmouse, mPY=_ymouse;
    //Aligning Control box+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //Vertical Align
    controls._visible = true;
    if (controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "top") {
        controls._y = controlBoxSpace;
    } else if (controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "middle" or controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "center" or controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "centre") {
        controls._y = (ih/2)-(controls._height/2);
    } else {
        controls._y = ih-controls._height-controlBoxSpace;
    }
    //Horizontal Align
    if (controlBoxHAlign.toLowerCase() eq "left") {
        controls._x = controlBoxSpace;
    } else if (controlBoxHAlign.toLowerCase() eq "middle" or controlBoxHAlign.toLowerCase() eq "center" or controlBoxHAlign.toLowerCase() eq "centre") {
        controls._x = (iw/2)-(controls._width/2);
    } else {
        controls._x = iw-controls._width-controlBoxSpace;
    }
    //Initial Zoom level detection. By default, the image gets scaled to the variable value "sc" to fit it within stage atleast to one side
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    sc = (ih/content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder._height)*100;
    if (!zoomOutToExtreme) {
        if (content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder._width*(sc/100)<iw) {
            sc = (iw/content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder._width)*100;
        }
    } else {
        if (content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder._width*(sc/100)>iw) {
            sc = (iw/content_clip.inner_clip.ImageHolder._width)*100;
        }
    }
```

The error messages are:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 14, Column 11  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before ne.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 26, Column 22  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before and.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 26, Column 63  1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before rightparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 67, Column 37  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before eq.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 69, Column 44  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before eq.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 69, Column 93  1008: Attribute is invalid.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 69, Column 102 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before or.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 71, Column 4   1083: Syntax error: else is unexpected.
```

Need to know, how to fix these above errors?

Comment: Does my answer fix your shown 8 errors? Use word search (Find/Replace tool) to replace those attributes (`ne`, `eq`, etc) quickly if too many to fix manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to research and use [**AS3 Operators**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html) on the parts of your code that have errors.

For example, your code seems to map to the following:

- Your `ne` is equivalent to AS3 operator : `!=` (see : [**`Not Equal`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#inequality)).
- Your `eq` is equivalent to AS3 operator : `==` (see : [**`EQuality`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#equality)).
- Your `and` is equivalent to AS3 operator : `&&` (see : [**`AND`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_AND)).
- Your `or` is equivalent to AS3 operator : `||` (see : [**`OR`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_OR)).

Example #1: (AS2 code):

```
if (image ne undefined and image ne "" and image ne null)
```

really should be (AS3):

```
if (image != undefined && image != "" && image != null)
```

Example #2: (AS2 code):

```
else if (controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "middle" or controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "center" or controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() eq "centre") {
```

really should be (AS3):

```
else if (controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() == "middle" || controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() == "center" ||controlBoxVAlign.toLowerCase() == "centre") {
```